# C# MVC powershell

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, powershell

I'm trying to build a C# MVC site and integrate Powershell scripts. The idea is to use the scripts I've already written. I cannot find the way to do this.

Is there someone who knows where to find a documentation?

THANK YOU VERY VERY much.

Paulo

Answer (score 1):

Really simple code project solution that should help you out

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C